# iText RadioGroup/RadioButtons across multiple PdfPCells

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'd like to make a PdfPTable with multiple rows in it.  In each row I'd like to have a Radio button in the first cell and descriptive text in the second cell.  I'd like all the radio buttons to be a part of the same radio group.

I've used PdfPCell.setCellEvent and my own custom cellEvents in the past to render TextFields and Checkboxes in PdfPTables.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it with Radio buttons/Radio groups.

Is this possible with iText?  Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [CreateRadioInTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CreateRadioInTable) example.

In this example, we create a `PdfFormField` for the radio group and we add it after constructing **and adding** the table:

```
PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.createRadioButton(writer, true);
radiogroup.setFieldName("Language");
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
// add cells
document.add(table);
writer.addAnnotation(radiogroup);
```

When we create the cells for the radio buttons, we add an event, for instance:

```
cell.setCellEvent(new MyCellField(radiogroup, "english"));
```

The event looks like this:

```
class MyCellField implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected PdfFormField radiogroup;
    protected String value;
    public MyCellField(PdfFormField radiogroup, String value) {
        this.radiogroup = radiogroup;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        final PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
        RadioCheckField radio = new RadioCheckField(writer, rectangle, null, value);
        try {
            radiogroup.addKid(radio.getRadioField());
        } catch (final IOException ioe) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(ioe);
        } catch (final DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking this a bit further...

If you're nesting a table of radio buttons (radio group) in another table you'll have to change the following from Bruno's example:

instead of

```
document.add(table);
writer.addAnnotation(radiogroup);
```

use (assuming you created a parent table and a PdfPCell in that table called parentCell)

```
parentCell.addElement(table);
parentCell.setCellEvent(new RadioGroupCellEvent(radioGroup));
```

with a parent cell event like so

```
public class RadioGroupCellEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {

    private PdfFormField radioGroup;

    public RadioGroupCellEvent(PdfFormField radioGroup) {
        this.radioGroup = radioGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
        writer.addAnnotation(radioGroup);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that ensures that your radiogroup is added on the correct page. Note that there are many other enhancements that are possible with respect to the appearance of the radio buttons. My code is just a proof of concept; it's a "naked" example ;-)